# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo

Tags: java, android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I know this question may be duplicate but I have tried many solutions but I am unable to make my app work. It should be noted that I have **enabled Multidex** but still getting below error. I am creating a **react native app**.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyy, PID: 3978
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4623)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing a react native application and above error came , just make sure that **all of your dependencies's Gradle are using same version of firebase servces and play service base**.
For example :- my app level gradle file contains

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.4.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.0"
```

and one react-native library is using

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
```

and other one library is using

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"
```

so what i did , i changed all services version to **11.8.0**.

BTW you can see gradles of all libraries or dependencies when you open your **react-native-project/android** folder in **Android studio**

I hope this will solve your issue